# Trying to find difference between ERC20 and ERC721, any help please?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, golang

[image: Node running code failure]

Getting this error when I try to run the following code which is supposed to check kthe receipt topics and if they are 4 then it should be ERC721 contract creation transaction and if 3  than it is ERC20, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please, share code and error messages as text. That way it is much easier to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you're trying to access the length of the topics array in the log object needs to change.

Try `len(receipt.topics)`